# Is it necessary to protect JAX-RS requests against CSRF?

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, jax-rs, csrf

Is it necessary to protect JAX-RS requests against [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)?

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Stateless) REST is stateless and therefore exists no session id (session cookie), because there is no session at all (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746639/5277820).

My Spring Security Java Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class JaxRsWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/services/**")
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/services/**").permitAll()              
                    .anyRequest().hasAuthority("ROLE_user")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

But I found for example following blog: [Stateless Spring Security Part 1: Stateless CSRF protection](http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/). Unfortunately the blog does not explain, why one needs CSRF protection.

Is there any other CSRF attack without session cookie?

Comment: you only need to protect them from CSRF if your site is used by web browsers. If it's only used by say curl, then you don't need to worry about CSRF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSRF attacks don't need a session to exist. A CSRF attack consists in doing something on a user's behalf by tricking him/her into clicking a link or submitting a form that goes to an application where the user is logged in.

Whether basic authentication or a session cookie is used to identify the user is irrelevant.

Note that using a cookie doesn't mean that the app is not stateless. A cookie, just like basic authentication, simply consists in sending an additional header with each HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks. For [Basic Authentication Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) I found the relevant part in [RFC 2617](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617#page-5): "A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
   the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
   are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of
   the current challenge. A client MAY preemptively send the
   corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in
   that space without receipt of another challenge from the server."

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens are sometimes stored in a (secured http-only at best) cookie, so that clients don't have to bother adding it in each request *manually*: cookies are automatically attached to the requests by the browsers. This is a reason why CSRF protection needs to be implemented.

The article you linked proposes to *have the clients generate and send the same unique secret value in both a Cookie and a custom HTTP header*, which is quite smart:

> Considering a website is only allowed to read/write a Cookie for its
>   own domain, only the real site can send the same value in both
>   headers.

That is, if you receive an email with a fake image targeting `http://yourserver.com/admin/deleteAll` for example (and the server handles it through `GET`...), the *unique secret* won't be set in the request header (an old one could still be present in a cookie): the server must reject the request.

Comment: I know, that cookies are automatically attached to the requests by the browsers, but I didn't know, that the authorization header is also automatically attached by the browser. The last one is indeed a problem with stateless (and cookie-less) JAX-RS requests.