# How to set cookies in AngularJS with Spring Security?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I am very new to Spring Security so to clear my concept I am developing an application which will send username and password to the Spring REST and Spring Security will use of `UserDetailService` to authenticate the user.

Up to now its ok I can understand, I configured the CORS filter to allow cross origin and I am getting correct response from Spring but I have some problem after that:

How I will store the cookie after authenticated by Spring Security?
What I am thinking is if Spring Security successfully authenticate the user I will use `$cookie` in Angular and store the username and password of user and each time I will send the username and password to access my protected resource?

I know this is something very basic and not a good idea to send username and password again and again but I dont know how to achieve this by sending cookie to the Spring REST.

Please help me to understand end to end flow of this.

Spring Configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/open/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/rest/secure/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic().realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeadersFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
     .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);//We don't need session.
    }
```

Comment: I made it stateless no I am not mentaining any session there

Comment: Simple http basic authentication with help of grant authorties and UserDetailsSerivce and I am using a filter which allow CORS nothing else.

Comment: Then you have to send HTTP authentication header (for HTTP Basic) with every request. You need no cookie.

Comment: you mean I have to send username and password with each request ?

Comment: Yes, because your REST API is stateless and you have no session.

Comment: Thanks dur , I need one clarification is it prevent csrf attack ,I disabled it so what should I do to enable it for csrf protection

Comment: If you use `stateless`, you cannot use Spring Security's CSRF protection, you have to build your own, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211562/is-it-necessary-to-protect-jax-rs-requests-against-csrf